# How does dart compile ,when not used with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

> In dart cli apps,does dart use the dart VM?Does it AOT compile the code by building an executable.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running your cli via [`dart run`](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-run) it will use the Dart VM. If you want an AOT binary, you'll want to compile your app via [`dart compile`](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile)

Comment: So dart compile won't use the VM?

Comment: Dart compile exe generates a standalone exe. No VM is required to run it.